# Discussion on a few elisp functions, like shell-command, start-process

Tags: emacs, elisp

(shell-command ...)

(async-shell-command)

(call-process ...)

(start-process ...)

What are the major difference and context to use them? It would be great if there's any summary? Bow//

Comment: The first few sections of http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html#Processes cover this completely.

Comment: This is not the place for discussion. This question should be closed as too broad, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

in short:

```
                     |  synchronous             | asynchronous
  -------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
  interactive        |  shell-command           | async-shell-command
  programmatically   |  call-process            | start-process

interactive: from the editing environment
programmatically: from elisp

synchronous: start and wait till done
asynchronous: start and return immediately while it is running in the background.
```

For more details : C-h f *name-of-function*